# How to use ng-messages for type='file'?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I'm using `ng-message` to show the error messages for the form it works fine for the `input type='text'` and other but how to use `ng-message` on `input type='file'` to show different messages based on the extension of the uploaded file.
Or is their any library that can provide error message?

Please guide me into this.

Comment: what are you encountering problems with input type='file'?

Comment: @DenisBokor how can i apply validation rules on type file like for extension.

Comment: oh, you want to add messages for different types of file?

Comment: use ngFileUpload https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ng-message error messages can be displayed this way

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <input id=choseefile type="file" ng-file="file" >
    <button ng-click="upload()">Upload</button>
    <div role="alert" ng-show="message.length>0">
        <li ng-repeat="msg in message">{{msg}}</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

and upload function as this:

```
$scope.upload = function() {
    $scope.message = "";
    $http({
    .........................
        }),
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        ...................

    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.message = [];
        $scope.message.push("Error Message");
    });

};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the file type on frontend then you can use this:

**HTML for this:**

```
<form name="radioForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
    <input type="submit"  ng-click="submitForm()">
</form>
```

**In controller:**

```
 $scope.submitForm=function() {
  if (document.radioForm.elements["uploadFile"].value == "") {
     alert("You forgot to attach file!");

  }
  var res_field = document.radioForm.elements["uploadFile"].value;
  var extension = res_field.substr(res_field.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
  var allowedExtensions = ['doc', 'docx', 'txt', 'pdf', 'rtf'];
  if (res_field.length > 0)
  {
     if (allowedExtensions.indexOf(extension) === -1)
     {
        alert('Invalid file Format. Only ' + allowedExtensions.join(', ') + ' are allowed.');
        return false;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's better to access the element via a directive's element, not via the document directly. You could read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background that can help you overcome this "jquery thinking"

Answer (score -1):

```
For the extension validation:
You can write this code in your validation method in backend:
 validatFile(your parameters)
 String fileName = file.originalFilename
            def matcher = (fileName =~ /.*\.(.*)$/)
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                def extension = matcher[0][1]
                if (!(extension in ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'txt'])) {
                    log.info("Invalid file format-------")
                    errMsg = "Invalid file format. Please add .doc .docx .xls .xlsx .pdf and text files only"

                }
            }
```

Comment: This code is for checking the file validation. If you want to add .png to be allowed add png in ['doc', 'docx', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'pdf', 'txt', 'png'].

Comment: It's not even javascript … In what way does that help the op?

Comment: its in grails..thats what i am suggesting use this in backend code.